# How to create a script which will automatically delete files from external disk which doesn't exist on the main volume

Tags: bash, macos

So first use Carbon copy cloner to clone my Mac contents to a 500GB disk. After that I use `rsync` to backup new files which was created on the main volume of my Mac. Well `rsync` can be useful for transferring edited and new files only. But `rsync` does not include changes such as if I move `~/f` to `~/folder/f` `rsync` copies the file to the folder on my external disk but does not delete the file from the external disk that is `/Volumes/HDD/~/f`. So can someone help me around with a bash script to help me achieve this?
Thanks!
By the way my Mac's bash version is 3.2.57.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Edit your Q to show  your best attempt at coding a solution to your problem. Sorry, but requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck

Comment: @shellter I did not know that I will make sure next Time I won't question off-topic questions here.

Answer (score 1):

> if I move ~/f to ~/folder/f rsync copies the file to the folder on my external disk but does not delete the file from the external disk that is /Volumes/HDD/~/f.

Use the `--delete option`.

#### Documentation

If you have special needs, there are variations on the `--delete` option that you may want to consider.  From `man rsync`:

> --del    --               an alias for --delete-during
>   --delete   --             delete extraneous files from dest dirs
>   --delete-before  --       receiver deletes before xfer, not during
>   --delete-during    --     receiver deletes during the transfer
>   --delete-delay       --   find deletions during, delete after
>   --delete-after     --     receiver deletes after transfer, not during
>   --delete-excluded    --   also delete excluded files from dest dirs
>   --ignore-missing-args  -- ignore missing source args without error
>   --delete-missing-args --  delete missing source args from destination
>   --ignore-errors   --      delete even if there are I/O errors
>   --force        --         force deletion of dirs even if not empty
>   --max-delete=NUM --       don't delete more than NUM files